# how would I use setInterval to execute a class function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this class called Warriors that will have a function called randomizeWinner which will delete a random element from the player's array, what I want to happen is for the elements to be deleted one by one through a set interval. Here is my code...

```js
class Warriors extends User {
  constructor(size) { super(size) }

  randomizeWinner() {
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.playersArray.length - 1)
    console.log(this.playersArray.splice(this.playersArray[random], 1))

  }


}

const w = new Warriors()

setInterval(w.randomizeWinner.bind(w), 3000)
```

So as you can see, the setInterval function at the bottom is where I am having trouble. How would I use the setInterval to implement the randomizeWinner function within the class

Comment: You should just be able to wrap that final line in a for loop, that iterates over each of the players (unless I've misunderstood the question)

Comment: @Lissy93 the players are in the user class it wouldn't work outside of the scope, would it?

Comment: "*So as you can see, the setInterval function at the bottom is where I am having trouble*" - no I can't see that, **what** trouble are you having?

Answer (score -1):

To have setInterval called automatically within in the class, you could just call it in the class constructor.

```
constructor(size) { 
 super(size) 
 setInterval(this.randomizeWinner, 3000)
}
```

When you create your object, `const w = new Warriors()`, it would be called within *that* object.